# Checking object as null using objectutils failed

Tags: java, object, java-8, is-empty

I am using `ObjectUtils.isEmpty()` as generic to check for the null and empty fields.It was working fine for the term like:

```
MyClass class = new MyClass()
class.setName(null);

if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(class.getName)) {
    return "Name";
}
```

But it is not working , when am trying it for the Object as below:

```
Object activatedDate = jsonObject.getJSONArray("records")
          .getJSONObject(i).get("ActivatedDate");
return ObjectUtils.isEmpty(activatedDate) ? null : "hello";
```

and My json is:

```
[
  {
    "LastModifiedDate": "2018-05-23T10:58:18.000+0000",
    "Order_Submission_Outcome__c": "test",
    "Number_of_Orders__c": 0,
    "Sales_Code__c": null,
    "Opportunity__c": "FERERR",
    "Contract_Type__c": "EZ Order Form",
    "StatusCode": "Draft",
    "CreatedDate": "2018-05-23T10:56:22.000+0000",
    "Id": "FERERR",
    "ActivatedDate": null,
    "Contract_Status__c": "ACTIVE",
    "Opportunity_Act_Total_Lines__c": 1
  }
]
```

But it always returns `hello` even though the object `activatedDate` is null. What is the problem?

Comment: *"But it always returns hello even though the object activatedDate is null."* That can't be the case. Please debug your code to see what's actually going on.

Comment: @buræquete yes that is org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.I already debug the code , that the activatedDate was null only.Actually I need to convert that object to date, I can't cast "null" to date right..So am checking for the null first and then trying to convert it.

Comment: Can you post the `JSON` that you are parsing?

Comment: @anchreg yes I posted my json.

Comment: the code you've posted seems to work fine. Please debug your actual code

Comment: Did you notice, how `class` was highlighted in you code snippet three times? You can’t name a variable “`class`”, as that’s a reserved keyword. So it’s hard to believe that this code snippet “was working fine”…

Comment: @anchreg Yes am debugging , still the same problem:-(

Answer (score 0):

In JPA QL if you want to call a database function it has to be done like this:

```
function(‘FUNC_NAME’, param1, param2,...)
```